# Handling network failure on AJAX requests

Tags: ajax, session

I need to be able to handle network failure on AJAX requests.  For example, a user looses their wifi connection.

What I could do is put a timeout on all AJAX requests and assume that if they timeout say after 15 seconds there is a network failure and just alert the user.

Is there better thing? Does force.com give us anything out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect an error code as the result, stating that the request took too long and timed-out (probably HTTP 408.) I generally just look for HTTP 200 (Response OK) to indicate success and anything in the 400-500s is an error.